# Separate BAD files for each file in External Table?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, rdbms, external-tables

I am trying to use an external table in Oracle to access multiple flat files in the same directory parallelly.

The problem here is that I am required to create a separate BAD file for each file (just like SQL*Loader does) instead of the single BAD file that external tables usually hold. Is there any workaround for the same?